# Preventing page from going to the top when using anchor on an external page

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I've spend hours trying to find a solution for this without any success. There are similar issues/solutions I've found but nothing seems to match the problem I'm having.

I have some external links on my page that contain an anchor tag. When clicked and the new page opens the browser goes to the top first then it goes to the actual anchor so the viewer can see an unpleasant jump on the page.

I'd like that when you click on the link, it takes you to the external page, straight to the anchor without going first to the top of the page.

```
<ul class="secNavSubPag">
  <li class="aboutSubMenu"><a href="about.php#offsetAnchor">our story</a></li>
  <li class="creatTeamSubMenu"><a href="creativeteam.php#offsetAnchor">creative team</a></li>
</ul>
```

The page that contains the anchor has this:

```
<a id="offsetAnchor"></a>
```

I haven't done this before so maybe I'm doing it wrong but any help is appreciated.

You can see the page here:
http://arthurscatering.com/devOct13/about.php

The links are in the Secondary nav, bottom left. The links are "our story" and "creative team"

Thanks again :0)

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done. Have you seen a working example of the effect somewhere?

Comment: No. I have not. I've tried doing a smooth scroll and other solutions to minify the effect but you can still see it.

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is to try a single page scrolling solution, something like: https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

Comment: The reason why I'm not using a single page solution is because this section is going to be all dynamic and when the admin adds a new page the picture at the top will change as well. So, I'm not even sure that you can do a tab navigation where the content change on separate 2 spots. (The picture and the text)

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't. And depending on the method you're using to insert new sections, you might not even have to so much. It' something to consider, at any rate.

Comment: Thanks todd. Let me see if I can find a solution to where it's a tabbed nav that triggers two spots.